# How do I format output in Mathematica to recognize variables are between zero and one?

Tags: output-formatting

I frequently work with variables that are between zero and one.  For example, if `r` is a depreciation rate:

```
Factor[k-r*k]
```

gives:

> ```
> -k (-1 + r)
> ```

which is correct but the result is an unintuitive product of 2 negatives.  How can I get the result to be:

> ```
> k (1 - r)
> ```

Note that this occurs with most Mathematica Functions, so ideally I would like to know if there is a global option that works for all functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `TraditionalForm`. In this case does not give exactly what you want,  but it often  improves output.

Comment: `expr /. a_*Plus[-1, r] :> -a*(1 - r)`

Comment: `// FullSimplify`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In this case, `Simplify` is adequate, but both destroy the factorization.